# Can't load a JSON from the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to load the JSON and alert it but I am not able to do this simple thing. I am confused have done this before but now it doesn't work. A simple fiddle would be helpful, this is how I tried it:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=get_list", function(json) {
alert("JSON Data: " + json.data.id);
});
```

I am getting the error...

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=get_list. Origin http://fiddle.jshell.net is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

for this I tried using a callback:

```
$.getJSON("https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=get_list&callback=?",function(json) {
 alert("JSON Data: " + json.data.id);
     });
```

and it threw up two errors:

Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/?action=get_list&callback=jQuery18205437749766279012_1353579335783&_=1353579335798". jquery-1.8.2.js:8304

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access data on another domain without [circumventing the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy).

You can't use JSONP to do that unless the service you are accessing supports JSONP, which `https://www.mariyano.com/app-server/test/` doesn't.

Comment: You would need to use serverside script to request the code, then use your jquery to request that local script.

Comment: What ss script are you using? PHP?

Comment: Hmm without access to the serverside you really are stuck :(

Comment: @KKSuhail — There are several workarounds listed in the answers to the question I linked to in this answer.

Comment: @Quentin thanks !! http://jsfiddle.net/YHPxs/8/ i found a way .... but how can i get just the first element

Answer (score 1):

I think one thing you should understand is the format of your JSON object. From the look of it, it looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {"id":"83","name":"asdas"},
    {"id":"86","name":"KKKK123"},
    {"id":"85","name":"KKKK123"},
    {"id":"82","name":"as"},
    ...],

  "status":1,

  "error":""
 }
```

You have 3 fields in your JSON object one called `data`, one called `status`, and one called `error`. Let's focus on the `data` field. It seems to be a giant array with objects at each index, each object containing fields including `id` and `name`.

Looking back at your code, you are trying to print `json.data.id`. The `json.data` is fine but when you say `id`... well it doesn't know which `id` it should be looking at so that's why it throws a syntax error.

the field `data` is an array so if you wanted to access a specific `id` you'd have to do

`json.data[0].id` and that'd give you the first index's `id`.

This at least explains the `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.

Comment: i tried that in this fiddle[link]http://jsfiddle.net/YHPxs/2/  but still the same error is there

Comment: I'm trying to play around with it but I'm not entirely sure why it is throwing a syntax error. You might need to [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) the `responseText` on the website before interacting with it but that requires ajax I believe. If you don't have access to the server, that might be hard. I would suggest finding a workaround for the first error before tackling the syntax error. Nevertheless though, your `data` field is an array so it's important to treat it like one :)

Answer (score -2):

Follow this code it may help you

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">

</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "mount rainier",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see how it is supposed to help at all. It is a mass of code for accessing a completely different webservice.